# How to stop downloading in Git Bash?

Tags: linux, command-line, linux-kernel, centos7, git-bash

I am trying to download a zip file from a particular website in git bash, but it's taking too much time , so my question is "how can I stop this downloading ?"

I know that Ctrl+C will immediately kill any process but it also throw me out from the VM, I need to re-login in order to use the VM . So, what I am asking is 'if there is any other way to stop this?'

Answer (score 0):

Use nohup to keep processes running while being able to continue other actions in the shell:

```bash
nohup git_command &
```

Review the output of the process:

```bash
tail nohup.out
```

Terminate the process when you need to, with `killall` or the specific PID:

```bash
killall git
```

```bash
kill 630916
```